# Do I need to know HTML and CSS to use jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile, web

Do I need knowledge to of HTML, CSS to use jQuery Mobile. I will use it in combination with Phonegap. I know this might sound strange, but does the framework creates its own CSS and HTML?

Comment: You should, unless you'll be building nothing more than a "hello world" app...

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you need to know CSS and HTML to do a lot of things. But if someone you know, knows those things, you could do without knowing them really well yourself.